# What is my Bianchi Model?

Tags: road-bike, serial-number

[image: Full picture]I've been looking for awhile on this Bianchi model number. My parents had this bike since before 2004 but they can't remember when exactly. Unfortunately there's no Bianchi official store in my country so it's a bit difficult to know.

Comment: Hi and welcome! More detailed shots would be appreciated, especially such indicative of the model (stickers on the seat tube or bottom bracket). Shots of drivetrain components often also help to narrow down the period, but for the most part: There is no detailed database of all bikes ever build. What are you trying to achieve with your question? If you just want to get the bike up and running, you don't really need that information since most parts are standard and can be swapped out (as long as the frame is intact).

Comment: Why are youn interested? if you think it has any commercial value: no, it does not. From the shape, it is a generic aluminium frame bike from the early 2000s, maybe early 2010s.
It is not one of the bicycle Bianchi is known for (road or roadish steel bike, or late 90s steel MTBs). And the Bianchi logo may just be a sticker ... https://a.d-cd.net/ab1f83u-960.jpg